# Elasticsearch Python API results in "search() missing 1 required positional argument" on a simple query

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, pyelasticsearch

I am desperately trying to perform a simple search operation on elasticsearch, but fail since hours. This is my code:

```
res = es.search(index="people", doc_type="test", body={"query":{"match":{"name": "john"}}})
```

I saw this many times on the internet, but I get always an error and have no clue what is wrong with my code snippet.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./es_request.py", line 14, in <module>
    res = es.search(index="people", doc_type="test", body={"query":{"match":{"name": "john"}}})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyelasticsearch/client.py", line 93, in decorate
    return func(*args, query_params=query_params, **kwargs)
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

Where do I have to write the required 'query'? I am trying to perform the search for name and last name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `search` method from [`pyelasticsearch`](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#pyelasticsearch.ElasticSearch.search) library (which you are using) calls the query argument `query`, not `body`:

```
 query = {"query": {"match": {"name": "john"}}}
 es.search(index="people", doc_type="test", query=query)
 es.search(query, index="people", doc_type="test")  # you can also do this
```

I think you meant to use the official [`elasticsearch`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) library, with which your code works perfectly fine (to add more confusion, its documentation is located at `elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io`).

Both libraries export the same module name, so things can sometimes *sort of* work when you use the wrong one. This is not a coincidence, [see this article](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elasticsearch-py/) on their history and differences. Installing the official client is easy as:

```
pip uninstall pyelasticsearch
pip install elasticsearch
```